# Can I specify a file instead of a directory to send to the container in the Dockerrun.aws.json file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I cannot find the reference documentation to the available fields in Dockerrun.aws.json.  I'm trying to import /dev/log from the host into the container so that I can centralize logs to logstash.

From the example, we can see that there is "HostDirectory" and "ContainerDirectory" however I can't find any analogue for "HostFile"/"ContainerFile".

How can I specify a single file to be shared with an elastic-beanstalk-enabled docker container?

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "my-bucket",
    "Key": "mydockercfg"
  },
  "Image": {
    "Name": "janedoe/image",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "1234"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/var/app/mydb",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/etc/mysql"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a host file as a data volume: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume

So you should be able to use the `"Volumes"` section to mount your file to your container.

```
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/dev/log",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/dev/log"
    }
  ]
```